# Will unpaid taxes prevent me from getting a business license?

Tags: united-states, taxes

When my trust fund matured I didn't pay the taxes and now I want to start a small business. Would the taxes I owe prevent me from obtaining the necessary licenses? Michigan.

Comment: Ummm, pay your taxes.  I mean that would be the smart thing to do.

Comment: Have you declared the income and reached an agreement with the IRS about paying the back taxes? Or are you saying that you lied on a tax form?

Comment: I payed half the debt so far. There is an agreement yet I'm looking at another year before the debt is satisfied.

Comment: If there's an agreement and you're paying as agreed then you're **fine**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally these things are unrelated. Your tax debt is to agency X, your license is (mostly) from agency Y.

If your business involves agency X, then it may be a problem. For example, you cannot get a EA license (IRS Enrolled Agent) if you have unsettled tax debt or other tax compliance issues. You should check Michigan state licensing organizations if there are similar dependencies.

Also, some background checks may fail, and some state licenses require them to pass. For example, you can probably not get an active bar registration or a CPA license with an unsettled tax debt. You might have a problem with registering as a Notary Public, or other similar position. You can probably not work in law enforcement as a contractor.

If you're on an *approved* payment plan - then your tax debt is *settled* unless you stop paying as agreed, and shouldn't be a problem.